# How can I avoid BCP T-SQL Bulk Insert Timeout?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, bcp

I am looking to deploy 124,978,454 rows of data to a production server.  After some research and asking around I arrived at using the bcp.exe to create a .dat file and then use T-SQL Bulk Insert to the destination table.  On the destination table I am disabling foreign keys as well as the non-clustered index on that table (but leaving the PK in tact).  **I am using SQL Server 2008 R2**.

I am using our dev environment to get an idea of how long I should expect the process to take.  So far, what I've done is:

1) Create the .dat file using bcp with the following command line code (I've anonymized it)

```
bcp "select * from MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable" queryout "c:\data.dat" -n -T -S Servername
```

2) Using the following T-SQL I am trying to bulk insert data

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE MYDATABASE SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED;

Use MYDATABASE 
GO

--Disabled indexes and foreign keys
ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

ALTER INDEX IDX_MyTable_ReportViewID ON MyTable DISABLE;

BULK INSERT MyTable
    FROM 'C:\data.dat' 
   WITH (DATAFILETYPE='native', BATCHSIZE = 50000); 
GO

USE master;
ALTER DATABASE MYDATABASE SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

This kicks off without a problem.  I let it run overnight but came back to the machine this morning to get a **timeout expired** error.

The error message is this:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

The Activity Monitor is unable to execute queries against server SERVERNAME.
Activity Monitor for this instance will be placed into a paused state.
Use the context menu in the overview pane to resume the Activity Monitor.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.2550&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
```

I have no idea when this error occurred as no datetime was given.  I need an estimate of how long this data transfer will take so I can plan for our deployment to production.

My research has turned up solutions for performing this task in C# which is not applicable to me.

### My question: How can I avoid this timeout error?

Alternatively, if there are options better than using the bcp utility I am willing to investigate those.

Comment: Activity monitor is a separate tool, I'm not sure if you need to worry about that.  Did all your data make it in?

Comment: Unfortunately all of the data didn't make it in.  It looks like only roughly 20% did, though I didn't think about the activity monitor being a separate tool so perhaps I was focusing on the wrong thing.